# How to update the Progress bar with the Time Remaining attribute in C#

Tags: c#, timer, progress-bar

I am developing a C# based Desktop application. As part of the report generation, I generate an Excel file. However as the number of entries increases, the time taken to complete the report generation also increases.

So, I am planning to create a progress bar which denotes the estimated time remaining.

- I would calculate the time taken for the 1st iteration ( `T_1` )
- I know the number of iteration ( `T_num` )

I am using the progress bar to update the progress :

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
progressBar1.Value = 1;
```

I am not able to connect these 2 parameters with the progressbar. Any idea how to do it ?

EDIT :

I am sorry, I missed this part in my question. I would like to display the estimated time remaining as well.

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting some kind of timer based callback to show partial iterations?

Answer (score 1):

If you set ProgressBar1.Maximum = T_num then you can simply increment the Value each iteration.